# DownloadProgressChanged JavaScript API For SilverLight

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am using Visual Studio 2012 in xaml "DownloadProgressChanged" is not available showing error "The property 'DownloadProgressChanged' was not found in type 'Image'."

```
<Image x:Name="Logo"
   Height="74" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="4,0,0,0"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Width="251" 
   Source="../Splash/logo.png" 
   DownloadProgressChanged="onSplashScreenLogoLoaded" 
   Opacity="0" 
   Stretch="Fill" />
```

Does vs2012 have any other event for this?

This is a SilverLight JavaScript API event.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Silverlight API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979859):

> No direct managed equivalent, and cannot be used as a XAML attribute on Image if using the managed API. You can however handle the BitmapImage.DownloadProgress event, either by using a verbose XAML syntax where BitmapImage can have a handler assigned by attribute for DownloadProgress, or through adding a handler (and setting the image source) in code.

Here is another method for media:

- [BufferingProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979887)